# Communication complexity

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, time-complexity

I am sending strings to a server and want to calculate the complexity.

For each string `s` I am sending all prefices of `s`. Therefore I start by sending one character, then two characters, then three ... up until sending `|s|` characters.

What is the communication complexity here? I would have said `O(|s|²)` but I am not certain.

Also in another algorithm I am sending for each character in `s` a fix-sized amount of data, let's say 100 characters. So I am sending `|s| * 100` characters. Now this should be in `O(|s|)` right? But which one is worse? Obviously for short `s` the first algorithm is better, or am I completely off here?

Answer (score 1):

Please, Correct me if I am wrong.

> sending one character, then two characters, then three ... up until
>   sending |s| characters.

When you send the first character, Are the remaining charcters (|S|-1) or are you starting again everytime |S|

- For the first possibility:

Let's say that |S|=n

1+2+...+n=n(n-1)/2

The complexity in this case is: O(|S|^2)

- For the second possibility: 
  1+2+...+a=|S|

The complexity in this case is: O(|S|)

Linear-time complexity is all the time better, check this tutorial for more information about [complexity time](http://web.mit.edu/16.070/www/lecture/big_o.pdf)

Comment: Yes it is the first one. But I am wondering, let's say I know that |s| is always smaller than 100 (and the linear time complexity has a factor 100), then wouldn't the `|s|^2` complexity be more efficient?

Comment: "efficient" is very subjective. If you have two solutions and you wanna compare, you can do decide which one is more efficient based on big-O complexity. But in this case, I don't see that you are have two approaches. if s is smaller than 100, it's not that problem (if you are aware of sorting algorithms, some researchers prefer using insertion-sort despite the fact that is quadratic, when they have small size of elements <100).

Answer (score 0):

Let c represent the factor in the second algorithm.  In your example, you set c to be 100.  Then your second algorithm will require c*|s| characters to be transferred.  As user3378649 pointed out, your first algorithm requires |s|*(|s|-1)/2 characters to be transferred.

So now, it should be easy to see that these have equal cost whenever c*|s| = |s|*(|s|-1)/2, or more succinctly:

c = (|s|-1)/2

Obviously, if c < (|s|-1)/2 then the cost of the second algorithm is less and if c > (|s|-1)/2, the cost of the first algorithm will be less.

Having said that, you should be considering these ideas as a practical matter:

1. What is your typical value for |s|?  If you have a guarantee that one of the inequalities is always met (such as if you can guarantee that |s| < 10), you should pick the appropriate algorithm.
2. How tolerant will your system be to longer delays?  If you consistently use the first algorithm, you may face trouble when you get an unusually large string.  Even if 99% of your data is really short, the potential user impact caused by long delays can be a problem.
3. You might consider using *both* algorithms: use the first algorithm when |s| is small and using the second algorithm when |s| is large.
4. Have you considered just sending the entire string in chunks of reasonable size, and letting the other side of the communication figure out the prefixes?  Data transfer is typically more expensive than computation time.  Also, the cost of initiating the communication has to be taken into consideration.  Communication transmissions typically use a block-size minimum, so breaking up small messages should be discouraged.

Good luck!